# Will an iterator surrounding an assert statement affect performance of production build?

Tags: java, performance, compiler-construction

I recently discovered the "[assert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)" statement in Java, and have been littering my software with them as I debug it. My initial instinct was to avoid making control flow statements just to handle assert statements, but then I realized that these control statements would probably be removed during a production build anyway, since their block would be empty. My impression is that they would be eliminated by the JIT compiler.

Unfortunately, I am working off of vague recollections of how the JIT compiler works, and cannot find appropriate documentation. The best I could find was this [brief outline](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/java7sdk/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.win.70.doc/diag/understanding/jit_optimize_flow.html) of the optimization process from IBM.

Before I get into the habit of implementing assertion-based tests, I wanted to know if there are best-practices to minimize their impact on performance. I'd hate to implement a bunch of tests only to find that their collective effect is to substantially decrease performance, even if individually their impact is negligible.

Can any of you tell me whether the following lines would be a drag on performance on a production build (with "assert" disabled, as is the default)?

```
for (T obj : Collection){
    assert obj.someProperty();
}
```

For a bonus, what if I were something more complicated, including short-lived objects that are only used for the assertions?

```
TreeMap<Integer,T> map = new TreeMap<>();
int i = 0;
for (T obj : Collection){
    map.put(i,obj);
    assert obj.someProperty();
    i++;
}
// assert something about map, then never use it again
```

Or a method whose only effect is to call "assert"?

Thanks in advance!

---

Relevant excerpts from Oracle's documentation of the "[assert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)" statement:

These discuss how to remove assert from the class file, which is not exactly what I'm concerned about.

> Removing all Trace of Assertions from Class Files Programmers
>   developing applications for resource-constrained devices may wish to
>   strip assertions out of class files entirely. While this makes it
>   impossible to enable assertions in the field, it also reduces class
>   file size, possibly leading to improved class loading performance. In
>   the absence of a high quality JIT, it could lead to decreased
>   footprint and improved runtime performance.
>
> The assertion facility offers no direct support for stripping
>   assertions out of class files. The assert statement may, however, be
>   used in conjunction with the "conditional compilation" idiom described
>   in the Java Language Specification, enabling the compiler to eliminate
>   all traces of these asserts from the class files that it generates:
>
> static final boolean asserts = ... ; // false to eliminate asserts
>
> if (asserts)   assert  ;

and from the FAQ section:

> Why not provide a compiler flag to completely eliminate assertions
>   from object files? It is a firm requirement that it be possible to
>   enable assertions in the field, for enhanced serviceability. It would
>   have been possible to also permit developers to eliminate assertions
>   from object files at compile time. Assertions can contain side
>   effects, though they should not, and such a flag could therefore alter
>   the behavior of a program in significant ways. It is viewed as good
>   thing that there is only one semantics associated with each valid Java
>   program. Also, we want to encourage users to leave asserts in object
>   files so they can be enabled in the field. Finally, the spec demands
>   that assertions behave as if enabled when a class runs before it is
>   initialized. It would be impossible to offer these semantics if
>   assertions were stripped from the class file. Note, however, that the
>   standard "conditional compilation idiom" described in the Java
>   Language Specification can be used to achieve this effect for
>   developers who really want it.

Comment: I don't recall enough details to give a confident answer, but I thought assertion enable/disable was at runtime, not compile-time.

Comment: @Brandon: thanks for the heads up. If that's the case, i guess the answer would be trivial. Maybe I need to read up a little on "assert". I'm adding a link to the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make method calls from within an `assert`, so the syntax I'd prefer is something like:

```
private static boolean testSomePropertyTrue(Collection<T> collection) {
    boolean test = true;
    for (T obj : collection){
        test = test && obj.someProperty();
    }
    return test;
}
```

...

```
assert testSomePropertyTrue(collection);
```

This leaves no ambiguity about code being optimized out by the JIT, and when assertions are enabled will perform the same invariant checks.

As written, your second example will always create the `TreeMap`, regardless of whether assertions are enabled. Wrapping the entire thing in an function and evaluating it as a single assert will completely eliminate that code path at run-time.

Like another answer to this question suggests, the assertions will leave behind bytecode regardless of whether they're enabled, but using the style shown above will deterministically prevent those codepaths from executing unless assertions are enabled.

Comment: Thanks. When you put it like that, it seems obvious. As you said, I noticed some drag from tests where I first collected information and then tested it with an assert statement.  One situation seems intractable -- I wanted to confirm that an updating procedure made the expected changes. This required saving the previous state prior to making the updates, and this was actually the resource-intensive step. I don't see any way to extract the test to a separate method while still updating the data.

Answer (score 0):

> Can any of you tell me whether the following lines would be a drag on performance on a production build (with "assert" disabled, as is the default)?

Your assertion loops will be run irrespective of whether asserts are on or off (i.e. they are part of the bytecode regardless -- assertions are enabled when *running* code). However, I wouldn't worry about performance regarding the first snippet; the JIT will likely realize that the loop isn't doing anything and take care of it early on.

> For a bonus, what if I were something more complicated, including short-lived objects that are only used for the assertions?

Something like your second snippet is harder to be sure about - the best thing to do would probably be to time it yourself, although in most circumstances I would imagine that it wouldn't have a noticeable effect either.

Perhaps you could have a "debug" flag and use it as such:

```
static boolean debug = true;

if (debug) {
    // loop here
}
```

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by saying that the loop "will be run" but the JIT will "take care of it"? That sounds like a contradiction. ps. I only have the vaguest understanding of the JIT system, so I may be mixing up some of the terminology. It's one of those things I need to review if I continue working with Java.

Comment: @adam.r Sure: I mean that the loop will exist at the bytecode level even if assertions are turned off (i.e. if you view the bytecode with `javac -p` then you will see the loop) (in fact, assertions are enabled when running code, not compiling), so it will essentially be equivalent to just having a loop with an empty body. In such situations, when the loop is executed, the JIT is smart enough to detect that nothing is happening in the loop, and optimize it away.

Comment: Your second loop is not so trivial, which is why I suggested it'd be best to time it yourself, if it's a real concern.

Comment: thanks. I apparently was conflating the bytecode compilation and the machine-code compilation (JIT, runtime). My concern is not so much that a single test will consume excessive resources, but that the sum total of many tests will be a significant resource hog (and difficult to identify as such). So I was hoping to get a general idea of how this would affect my program(s) before making a habit of designing tests like this.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the iterator involved in the loop, the analysis required to determine the loop is all dead code may be beyond current JITs, so I wouldn't rely on it being eliminated. At a very minimum use `-XX:+PrintCompilation` to make sure it actually is eliminated on the JIT you are using in production.